# Typescript module xyz has no experted member for library node_modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules

[image]For well known library modules like `mobx` or `react-native` or any other node module.

Typescript ide shows an error saying Module `mobx` has no exported member `inject`.

Answer (score 0):

For an in-depth process followed by typescript in order to resolve modules,
one can refer to the following doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules

Also on top of that the module resolution process can be complicated and one can trace the module resolution using following command:

```
tsc --traceResolution
```

Even if you are still having issues try:
1. Ctrl/Cmd click on the module and see where it takes you.
2. If there is a file named `libdefs.js`, try deleting it and see.

Figure out the documentation for `libdefs.js` and evaluate its necessity.